# Plot disappears when changing axis titles in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis-labels

When I try to change the axis titles of a ggplot2 plot using `+labs('text')`, the plot completely disappears and I cannot figure out why. 
Maybe you can help

So I have the following dataframe:

```
d <- read.table(text='samples variable       value
UT            F201/203   0.002558366
siCTL         F201/203   0.009112220
siF201/203    F201/203   0.004739938
UT            F203       0.010881532
siCTL         F203       0.022440469
siF201/203    F203       0.011569276
UT            F203/206   0.003923319
siCTL         F203/206   0.010474094
siF201/203    F203/206   0.004946134',   header=TRUE)
```

I then create the boxplots using:

```
pd<-ggplot (data=d, aes(x=samples, y=value)) 
 pd + geom_bar (aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

this come out
[image]

I then want to change the y axis title (the same happens when I try to change the x axis title) using:

```
pd + labs(y="relative expression")
```

But then the plot completely disapears:

[image]

The answer is probably very simple, however I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Thank you

Comment: you haven't resaved `pd` with the `geom_bar()` layer, `pd <- pd + geom_bar (aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")`

Comment: Thank you, I knew this was simple but I am too stupid (or tired) to see it.